# access html tag property inside itself with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this html code :

```html
<label [class]="text === 'test1' : 'class1' : 'class2'" text="test1"></label>
<label [class]="text === 'test1' : 'class1' : 'class2'" text="test2"></label>
```

I want to access the text property of those labels inside the class tester but I doesn't seem to be the right syntax and cannot find answer if it is possible and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a template variables to the labels and use them.

```
<label #lbl1 [class]="lbl1.text === 'test1' : 'class1' : 'class2'" text="test1"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, I've found it in the docs since :
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context